# Why pop_back() method is different in vector and list class?

Tags: c++

I am studying C++ Standard Template Library and I have noticed something. Here is the code:

```
int arr[] = {80, 70, 50, 30};
vector<int> ivect(arr, arr+4);

for (int i = 0; i < ivect.size(); i++) {
    cout << ivect.back() << " ";
    ivect.pop_back();
}
```

The output of this code snipped is this:

```
30 50
```

But when I changed the type of ivect to list, for example:

```
int arr[] = {80, 70, 50, 30};
list<int> ilist(arr, arr+4);
int size = ilist.size(); // Also I don't understand this.
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cout << ilist.back() << " ";
    ilist.pop_back();
}
```

It gives me a proper output:

```
30 50 70 80
```

I mean, when I use vector class, it excludes some parts. Why is that happens?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce.](http://ideone.com/RmSRRX) As expected, the list version gives the same output as the vector version, since `size()` is 2 by the end of the loop.

Comment: They give different output because the code is not the same (since your edit). In the second version you make sure the size does not change during the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it has nothing to do with using `vector` instead of `list`

when you do: 
`for (int i = 0; i < ivect.size(); i++)`
the vector size is evaluated in each iteration. As it decreases with each `pop_back`, it finishes after two iterations.

On the other hand, when you do

```
int size = ilist.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

the loop condition is fixed to `i<4`, whether the actual size changes or not.

Answer (score 1):

consider this

```
  for (int i = 0; i < ivect.size(); i++) {
    cout << ivect.back() << " ";
    ivect.pop_back(); 
 }
//first iteration i=0 to 3; Now after pop_back size reduces by 1
//second oteration i=1 to 2;Now after pop_back size reduces by 1
//3rd iteration i=2 to 1;//loop does'nt execute.
```

In every iteration you are calculating the size of the vector and size is reduced by `1` everytime.
EDIT: Now since the code is changed,in the `list` version size is not calculated everytime,hence the different result.

Answer (score 1):

Both should work the same, although I think the real issue is that you expect your code to pop all the elements of the vector/list but the way you wrote it, it will actually only pop half the list.

`ivect.size()` is being evaluated every time through the loop. Since you are popping items off, the size is decreasing, meaning once `i` is 2, the size will be 2, and the loop will stop. What you need to do is store the size before the loop in some variable.